# This file does not belong to the project : IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

I am New to java and
Just installed JDK and IntelliJ IDEA
I created a project in IntelliJ IDEA

- The below picture shows The project structure

[image]

- However When I edit the file It shows: This file does not belong to the project
  [image]

And the Main.java file formed is not showing in the project.

- The complete structure is as follows

[image]

I dont know If this makes any sense But, In the tutorials I have watched, unlike in my case the src folder is present under the project itself.

I would Highly appreciate If someone could help

Comment: you need to create a **Java Project** in IntelliJ and put the file in the `src` folder

Comment: See a step-by-step tutorial at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html .

Comment: delete the ./idea directory and reopen the directory with idea will solve the problem